# how to get "My Music" Folder path of any computer using java code

Tags: java, path, directory

In my Computer path is C:\Users\RS\Music
How to get the C:\Users\RS as the initial path may vary for every different user on same computer.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: please explain what you want to do, along with with your effort

Comment: @BlueBullet No, the question is not nonsense, but it might be, that the answer is: *"There is no system property like `user.home`. But if you are referring to the windows 'Music' folder in the home dir, you can access that using `System.getProperty("user.home")`."*... In that case, why don't you post this answer instead of ranting at newer members that don't have the same knowledge level than you have?

Answer (score 3):

System.property has an entire set of [interesting keys](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm) to draw information out of.
One of them is "user.home", it should contain the information you need.

Comment: No it does not, it only returns the "C:\Documents and Settings\Username" part. "My Documents" and "My Music" are named as such only on English Windows, in does not work in localized versions

Comment: the question is: "How to get the C:\Users\RS as the initial path may vary for every different user on same computer."

in that case my answer is valid. i agree it's not the full solution to the problem, but it's the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the location of the Music folder then you have to read the Windows registry in order to do this. Some ways to read the windows registry are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

As for the specific registry key you need, for Windows XP it is the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\My Music` key. For Windows 7, I'll update my answer when I have access to a PC that has it installed.

Comment: This is Windows specific, I'm on Linux and I have a 'Music' folder in the XFCE interface. How do you do this in Linux?